# The image of a specific Mobius transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Let $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{C} :f(z)=\frac{z}{z-1}$ and $D= \{ z:|z|=1\}$ ,what is the image of $f$, $f(D)$?

Can one elaborate on some general methods of dealing with these kind of questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to note here:

1. A Mobius transformation maps a circle to either a line or a circle.
2. A Mobius transformation is uniquely determined by the images of three points.

Now, in your case, we have

- $f(1)=\infty$
- $f(-1)=1/2$
- $f(i) = (1-i)/2$

Now, since $f(1)=\infty$, the image must be a line, rather than a circle. By the other two computations, that line must go through $1/2$ and $(1-i)/2$.  If you happen to be interested in the interior of the circle, then you simply check the image of some simple point in the interior.  In this case, $f(0)=0$. Thus, the interior maps to the side of the line that contains the origin.

Comment: How do you know 1 and 2 are true